# Как загружать видео в озу ранее требуемого Android

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ram

У меня есть видео в какой-то папке, и я знаю что через пару секунд он будет загружен в память, но тогда перед показом он пару секунд(1-2) оно будет качаться, и мне надо это исправить (что бы использования видио, оно не грузилось), видео находится в папке /Resources/raw/xamar.mp4
Использую Xamarin Form + Xamarin Community Toolkit

Comment: Если оно локально в папке, то оно не будет качаться пару секунд, так как скорость чтения с носителя быстрее, чем скорость воспроизведения.

Comment: @aepot если это какой-нибудь HDD не первой свежести, то даже скачать из интернета может оказаться быстрее...

Comment: Я не уверен, что кто-то с HDD не первой свежести будет смотреть 4К видосы. В противном случае даже старый HDD вытянет чтение 1,7 МБ/сек (это 1080p). Кстати, при чем тут HDD, если речь про телефоны на андройдах?

Comment: @aepot я в этом вопросе не вижу упоминания ни андроидов, ни телефонов (а Xamarin это не только про телефоны)

Comment: @aepot но даже с андроидами ситуация ещё веселее, потому что в дешёвой китайщине встроенная память может оказаться ещё медленнее чем даже HDD не первой свежести)

Comment: @andreymal ок, вам виднее

Comment: У меня видео локально в папке, а Xamarin для андроида, уточню